# Spring boot API in cloud not as fast as in local

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a spring boot API that returns media data files such as pdfs, images in base64 format. The problem is that I get a response time that is three or four times slower than local. The application is hosted in the PCF cloud.

Here are some cloud insights:

response_time: 32.0000 seconds, gorouter: 0.000359s.

I also placed logs at the beginning and at the end of the controller. The time difference is around 1-2 seconds. After that,  the PCF log with the response time and gorouter entries come up showing above metrics.

It doesn't make any sense the cloud takes so long in processing while locally it just takes 7 seconds based on the postman response time. My computer can't be faster than these PCF instances.

what could be the possible reasons why the response time is so high?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of many reasons like

1. Memory limit of your app
2. What's the app doing? Does it make any
   egress connection to any DB or API and is there any network glitch?
3. Is it CPU intensive? Usually local doesn't get such issue highlighted

You may probably use PCF App metrics to get more information from your application or tracing can help breaking it down further

Comment: Hi Jain, as I mentioned above the code is not an issue as it executes within milliseconds the issue what happens after the code returns.